Using class methods in different namespace
I have a Class named ButtonHelper.cs in the WpfApp2 directory and another MainWindow.xaml in the same directory i can access the method in the ButtonHelper.cs class in the MainWindow.xaml but i also have a page inside of the WpfApp2/Utility/FirstPage.xaml and i want to access that method in this page too. Can i do it?
namespace for the Main Window XAML - xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
namespace for the ButtonHelper class - namespace WpfApp2
namespace for the FirstPage XAML - xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.UtilityPages"
I am confused I am a newbie so i can't make a guess how does this work.
